# GRUB not recognising copied partition

Tags: boot, grub2, partitioning

I've been following the instructions on [this page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MovingLinuxPartition) to copy my Linux partition from one partition to another on the same drive. (I'm doing this because I want to move it from /dev/sda3 to /dev/sda4 so that I can then resize /dev/sda2 and use my drive more efficiently).

I got up to "**1. Reboot you machine again**" under Step 6, but 'UBUNTU' on the copied partition never appears in the grub boot menu. I only ever see my original /dev/sda3 version. I have tried reinstalling GRUB and it says it's been successful, but there's no change.

Are those instructions wrong? Is there just something wierd with my computer? Can you suggest how to get this working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of fiddling, I worked this one out myself. I needed to repair GRUB using the instructions [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows).

Quick precis of the steps:

Boot in to live CD.
Mount the new partition to /mnt:

```
sudo mount /dev/sda2 /mnt  # make sure that sda2 is correct!
```

Bind the various local directories so that chroot will work:

```
for i in /sys /proc /run /dev; do sudo mount --bind "$i" "/mnt$i"; done
```

chroot in to the new partition:

```
sudo chroot /mnt
```

At which point you're running Ubuntu in the new partition. Then from there, update and reinstall GRUB:

```
update-grub
grub-install /dev/sda
```

You might need to update GRUB again afterwards.

Then reboot and the GRUB menu will be updated.

At that point I booted in to the new partition, deleted the old one, and updated GRUB to reflect that change.

Answer (score 0):

**Boot into the *live CD*** and then do this in the terminal

> **sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get update**

Let it do its thing, and then do this

> **sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair**

**follow the defaults** "Fix most common problems" or whatnot
If it breaks again, come back.